# Here XYZ Studio issue with uploading files

Tags: csv, geojson, here-api

It seems that the XYZ Studio has some problems with accepting files. The upload of .geojson and .csv files is recommended but it tells me i am trying to upload "unsupported file types". It still worked a few weeks ago but i cannot upload any .geojson and .csv files right now.

Comment: Do you have an example from the geojson or csv files you are trying to upload?

Comment: @j12y I managed to fix the problem. But there wasn´t anything really special about it. I had the columns "Name", "Lat", "Lng" and "Type". It seems that XYZ Studio had some issues with "Lat" and "Lng"; i dindt know that i have to write out the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly crosscheck the names in the header of your csv file. If the file does not have columns labelled Latitude and Longitude, the xyz studio may give you a message saying that you are trying to upload an unsupported file.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem.

I used to name the columns "Lat" and "Lng" a while ago and i remember that it worked. Maybe Here changed something in the workings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. Turns out HERE Studio prefers comma (,) CSVs only.  If modifying in excel and it gets saved as a caret (^) CSV, the uploader will only read the file as one wide column and pop out errors.

If HERE is listening, some documentation on properly formatted file types, formats, and limitations along with sample code for the .CSVs, json, shape, and GEOjson files would be immensely helpful to users of Studio as there is little in the way on the API/platform documentation.